# Why doesn't my PreparedStatement SQL query work? Only works with a hardcoded string

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector

I'm trying to use a `PreparedStatement` to generate an SQL query. It works perfectly fine when I use a hard coded `String` or with concatenation, but I am absolutely lost about why it's not working when using a `PreparedStatement`.

```java
public Customer createCustomer(Customer customer) {

     //Ommitted code

     int result = statement.executeUpdate(createPreparedStatementQuery(customer), Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)
);
```

Creating the query with a PreparedStatement

```java
public static String createPreparedStatementQuery(Customer customer){
    String query = "INSERT INTO customers(Customer_Name, Address, Postal_Code, Phone, Created_By, Last_Updated_By, Division_ID) " +
            "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, (SELECT Division_ID FROM first_level_divisions WHERE division = ?));";
    try {
        PreparedStatement statement = ConnectionManager.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
        statement.setString(1, customer.getName());
        statement.setString(2, customer.getAddress());
        statement.setString(3, customer.getPostalCode());
        statement.setString(4, customer.getPhoneNumber());
        statement.setString(5, customer.getCreatedBy());
        statement.setString(6, customer.getLastUpdatedBy());
        statement.setString(7, customer.getDivision());
        
        System.out.println(statement); //Successfully returns the query
        
        return statement.toString();
    }catch (SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

This gives the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement: INSERT INTO
> customers(Customer_Name, ' at line 1

However, the query executes perfectly fine with a String created by concatenation or hardcoded.

```java
public static String createConcatQuery(Customer customer) {
    String query =  "INSERT INTO customers(Customer_Name, Address, Postal_Code, Phone, Created_By, Last_Updated_By, Division_ID) " +
            "VALUES ('"
            + customer.getName() + "', '"
            + customer.getAddress() + "', '"
            + customer.getPostalCode() + "', '"
            + customer.getPhoneNumber() + "', '"
            + customer.getCreatedBy() + "', '"
            + customer.getLastUpdatedBy() + "', "
            + "(SELECT Division_ID FROM first_level_divisions WHERE division = '"
            + customer.getDivision() + "'));";
    System.out.println(query);
    return query;
}
```

```java
String hardCodedQuery = "INSERT INTO customers(Customer_Name, Address, Postal_Code, Phone, Created_By, Last_Updated_By, 

Division_ID) VALUES ('ee', 'ee', 'ee', 'ee', 'test', 'test', (SELECT Division_ID FROM 

first_level_divisions WHERE division = 'Newfoundland and Labrador'));";
```

I've copied and pasted both the queries outputted from the log. The concat query and preparedstatement query both return the same String:

[image]

I am absolutely lost on why it doesn't work at this point. Could someone please help me figure out what I'm doing incorrectly using the `PreparedStatement`?

Full StackTrace:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement: INSERT INTO customers(Customer_Name, ' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1337)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2117)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1342)
    at sample.data.CustomerRepository.createCustomer(CustomerRepository.java:144)
    at sample.controller.CustomerController.createCustomer(CustomerController.java:165)
    at sample.controller.CustomerController.confirmAlert(CustomerController.java:153)
    at sample.controller.CustomerController.onBtnSaveClick(CustomerController.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:410)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$3(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: executeUpdate cannot be called on a PreparedStatement or CallableStatement. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the `statement.executeQuery()` in your `createPreparedStatementQuery()` function. Or you could return your statement object from `createPreparedStatementQuery()` function and call `statement.executeQuery()` in your `createCustomer()`.

N.B. You can use `statement.executeUpdate()` or `statement.executeQuery()` depending on what you want.

What your `createPreparedStatementQuery()` is basically doing is that it is returning the original query with ? marks in it to the statement object in `createCustomer()`. The statement object outside does not know about about parameters you set in the inside statement object.

Comment: My mistake was thinking I had to convert the ```PreparedStatement``` to a string then executing ```statement.executeUpdate(preparedStatementString, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS); ``` When I could've just called ```preparedStatement.executeUpdate();```